# Lowering annealing temperature in PCR

Tags: pcr

In the book "Lewin's Genes" there is the following quote:

> Lowering the Tm of a PCR reaction—in effect, relaxing the reaction stringency and **allowing primers to anneal to not quite
> perfect hybridization partners** — has useful applications, as well, such as in searching a sample for an unknown sequence suspected to be similar to a known one.

Why is this so? That is, why does lowering the annealing temperature in a PCR reaction reduce a specificity of hybridization, more precisely?

Comment: https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/cloning/cloning-learning-center/invitrogen-school-of-molecular-biology/pcr-education/pcr-reagents-enzymes/pcr-cycling-considerations.html, see section "Primer annealing optimization".

Comment: Perhaps more specifically, see section "Effect of annealing temperature on primer mismatch" here: https://academic.oup.com/femsec/article/60/2/341/584515

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.